# How to play web page mp3 url in HTML5 player?

Tags: javascript, php

I am working on a page where i have multiple mp3 links (url) for example,

```
<a href="http://www.domain.com/song.mp3" rel="nofollow" target="_blank"> play </a>
```

I would like to play them in a player using playlist and also a download button. Is there any easy way i can get it done!

Thank you all.

Comment: before do that change `www,` to `www.` in your `href`!

Comment: You need a player of some kind, not the one that opens in some browsers when you open an mp3 link, but a player embedded into the page. Look for HTML5 Audio tags.

Comment: Some browsers don't support mp3 files

Comment: http://www.w3schools.com/html/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml5_audio_all

Comment: I just trying to play all mp3 links in a player like yahoo media player but i don't wanna use web player cause it has no download link.